# keep the hover effect on click

Tags: css, onclick, hover

i want to keep the hover effect of my div when i click on it how can i do it ? 
There is my code:
i actually want my div with the red background stay in the hover place 
when i click on the "work" button

```css
#work_btn{
 position:absolute;
 top:60%;
 left:60px;
 color:grey;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #ff956c, #ff3644);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 text-align:left;
 z-index:20; 
}


#blank_work{
 position:absolute;
 width: 80px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-top:100px;
 background:red;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 -moz-transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
 transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}



.button_cadre_work:hover #blank_work{
 margin-top:100px;
 margin-left:80px;
}
```

```html
            <a href="#"><div class="button_cadre_work"><div id="work_btn">WORKS</div>
              <div id="blank_work"></div>
               </div></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use javascript to toggle a class when the link is clicked.

You would then style the link with the active class the same way you do on hover.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s81yo6s5/

You can use this javascript to toggle an `is-active` class on your `.button_cadre_work` element:

```
var button = document.querySelector(".button_cadre_work");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   this.classList.toggle("is-active"); 
});
```

and then style it the same as the hover:

```
.button_cadre_work:hover #blank_work,
.button_cadre_work.is-active #blank_work {
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:80px;
}
```